# Weird issue with range based for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, ranged-loops

I am working on learning vectors in my C++ object oriented 1 class and we have been introduced the concept of range based for loops. I decided to practice the range based for-loops separately so that I could get used to the syntax but I came across a weird issue.

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
   int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
   for ( auto i: a)
     {
       cout << a[i] << " ";
     }

 return 0;
 }
```

When I run the above code my output is the following.

> 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 Press any key to continue...

My output should read

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 Press any key to continue...

Can anyone tell me why my first index is skipped? I have visual studio 2013 professional.

Comment: You should not print `a[i]` but just `i`

Comment: the range based for loop iterates over the elements, not the indices of the array

Comment: WOAH! IT WORKS! But how@DragonRock doesn't i just correspond to the index of the array? From 0-9? Or am I way off base here?

Comment: i is not an index to a but the first value of a, each time though the loop i is the next value of a. Change the type a to string, your a[i] won't compile,

Comment: you've just discovered an excellent technique for code obfuscation!! :-)

Comment: @RichardHodges, this is how JavaScript works, BTW. I was ready to bang my head the other day, when I needed to do small changes to some web script. Finally I realized that JS's for each loop iterates over indexes (or keys in assoc arrays), not values! They have the newer version in ECMA script, which iterates over values - but of course, not supported by our version of IE.

Comment: Thanks for all the amazing feedback. I'm going to write some test code and see how this works with templates and classes just to tie it all together. I learned a lot here thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get the weird output because `i` in the range loop is the value from the array, not an index. That is,

```
for (auto i : a)
```

loops through the *values* of `a`. In your code you're effectively printing the sequence `a[a[0]]`, `a[a[1]]`, etc.

The code you probably want is

```
for (auto i : a) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```